# How to change svn working copy between two different repositories?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

We had a repository with a size of 5 gigs.  It was a mistake so we run an svnadmin dump and then svnfilter all unneeded files.  Now the repository is 500 megs.  We want to point the working copies of the old repository (5 gigs) to the new repository.

Will svn switch work? if not, how we do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check out a new working copy, svn switch will not work in these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

SVN switch is designed to be used and usually applied to cases, when both locations share common ancestry and it can mess up with 2 different repos and results of this action are unpredictable :)

I suggest you to use svn diff to generate diff files, then checkout new working copy, and apply patch to it .